# android studio shows a blue screen in Hello world program

Tags: android

[image]

This image shows a blue screen parallel to the main screen of the phone.
I want to remove it if possible as the videos from which I am learning to code does not have it.

Comment: That is important as it shows how the layout is divided as a "blueprint". It does not affect the code, so it does Not matter if your video has it or not

Comment: Choose "design" from Select Design Surface.

Comment: That is called *a blueprint*, and it is a new feature. It should really give no influence on your tutorials.

Answer (score 4):

It's really quite simple actually. Although it doesn't make any difference if you remove it or not from the tutorial.[image]

Click here and you will get 4 options. Click on

> Design

The blueprint will no longer be there.

Answer (score 0):

You needn't remove it. It is a special feature of `Android Studio`.

The videos which you are watching ought to be either of old versions of `Android Studio` or maybe using other IDEs like `Eclipse ADT`.

However, I think you might be able to remove it by taking a deep dive into `Android Studio`'s settings.